# "Recognition" of scholarly journals

Tags: journals

Are there some academic fields in which there is such a thing as official recognition of scholarly journals, so that speaking of a journal as being "recognized" or "unrecognized" would be generally understood by those in the field without any accompanying explanation?

I encountered someone on the internet saying that the unrecognized status of a certain journal in health sciences was of some consequence. But he got bored and went away when I posed this question.

Note: "Anonymous mathematician" wrote in a comment "I see this usage as being like the term 'recognized expert' (which is talking about reputation rather than certification)." But although the term "recognized" is used in that way, "unrecognized" in general usage often refers to something official or precisely defined. "Ian_Fin" wrote in a comment below: "Recognised by who?".  But that of course was a substantial part of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by recognition? Beyond the obvious, what would be the difference between a recognised and an unrecognised journal? Recognised by who? I flagged this question as unclear.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the person on the internet was talking about official recognition.  For comparison, there's certainly no notion of official recognition of mathematics journals, but if someone referred to a certain journal as being recognized or unrecognized, I think it would be generally understood and agreed upon.  I see this usage as being like the term "recognized expert" (which is talking about reputation rather than certification).

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician : It seems the word "recognized" is often used in the way you describe, but "unrecognized" usually means something official, or the absence of something official.

Comment: @Ian_Fin : That's what _I_ was asking!

Comment: @MichaelHardy: That's a good point.

Comment: I'll take New England Journal of Medicine as an example. Is it recognized? I think most people would agree that it is recognized in medicine. Is it _officially_ recognized? Then people would argue what do you mean by "official". This question is unclear to me in the sense that what "official" is. Would you please consider rephrasing the question so that it is clear?

Comment: Judging by your "clarification", this question seems to be more about the semantics of the word  "recognized" than anything having to do with academic journals.

Comment: @ff524 : I don't think so. For example, in the fields of chemistry and astronomy, there are professional bodies that decree what "correct" technical terminology is. This is somewhat like that.

Comment: It appears that what you mean to ask is something like: "Are there academic fields in which some professional body maintains a list of 'recognized' journals, such that work in journals not on that list tends to be discounted by scholars in the field?"  Is that about right?

Comment: @MarkMeckes : Yes.